# ng-click - displaying message that checkbox is required

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an element which has ng-click function. On click it performs certain action. I also have a checkbox which must be checked to perform such action.

If it is not checked it should show an error message for the user that it's required.

How do I add this kind of form validation?

element:

```
<a ng-click="assignSubmission(subItem.id)" class="action-button"> 
    <i class="icon icon-star"></i> Assign
</a>
```

its action code:

```
$scope.assignSubmission = function(scope) {
    var url = Django.url('submission:assign', {
        site : site
    });
    $http.post(url, $scope.selected_items).success(function(data) {
        updateDashboardService.update_dashboard();
    });
};
```

Checkbox which should have an error message:

```
<input ng-disabled="subItem.operator" ng-if="subItem.level != 0" 
    type="checkbox" name="submissiongroup" 
    ng-model="selected_items[subItem.id]" 
    ng-click="selectCheckbox($event, subItem)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In JS:

You have a ng-model in check box. If the check box is unchecked then it is undefined. Use that to display a message.

```
$scope.CheckFun = function(){
    $scope.Msg = undefined;
```

//$scope.selected_items is the ng-model of check box here.

```
    if($scope.selected_items == undefined){
        $scope.Msg = "Please check it out";
     }
 }
```

In html:

```
<div ng-show = "Msg">{{Msg}}</div>
```